# Temp Table with XML column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table in `SQL Server` and I am putting the values of the result set from the table into `XML` like this:

```
select 
  lAccountID,
  sName,
  sAge
from 
  AccountDVDetails 
where 
  laccountID = 10 
for xml raw ('Values'), ROOT ('Accounts'), ELEMENTS
```

This query gives me `XML` like

```
<Accounts>
<Values>
  <lAccountID>10</lAccountID>
  <sName>A</sName>
  <sAge>21</sAge>
</Values>
<Values>
  <lAccountID>10</lAccountID>
  <sName>B</sName>
  <sAge>22</sAge>
</Values>
<Values>
  <lAccountID>10</lAccountID>
  <sName>C</sName>
  <sAge>23</sAge>
</Values>
</Accounts>
```

Now I want to store this `XML` with `lAccountId` in a temporary table `#tmpAccount` like

```
   lAccountId     XMLValue
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     10           <Accounts><Values><lAccountID>10</lAccountID><sName>A</sName><sAge>21</sAge></Values><Values><lAccountID>10</lAccountID><sName>B</sName><sAge>22</sAge></Values><Values><lAccountID>10</lAccountID><sName>C</sName><sAge>23</sAge></Values></Accounts>
```

How can I achieve this? I have tried putting the `XML` into `string` variable but the `XML` gets truncated to a certain limit.

Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need this for many `lAccountID`s in one go or this always bound to one ID (in this case 10)?

Comment: @Shnugo Yes I need this for many `lAccountID` in one go

Comment: The accepted answer does not really cover this... Were you able to solve this on your own?

Comment: @Shnugo Yes I did tried by myself but I could not end up with a efficient solution for the same. I will really appreciate, if you can help me with that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for a nested, hierarchical XML for many Accounts

First I declare some table variables to *mock-up* a test scenario. I assume, that there is a parent table with accounts:

```
DECLARE @dummyAccount TABLE(lAccountID INT IDENTITY,SomeData VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @dummyAccountDetail TABLE(lAccountDetail INT IDENTITY,lAccountID INT,sName VARCHAR(100),sAge INT);--do not store the age as int but the DoB!!!

INSERT INTO @dummyAccount VALUES('Account 1'),('Account 2');
INSERT INTO @dummyAccountDetail VALUES(1,'Jane',20),(1,'John',30)
                                     ,(2,'Tim',40),(2,'Tom',50);
```

The query will list the accounts as first level (I added some descibing attributes just to show the principles, but you can easily let them away. The sub-select will create an XML for each account separately.

```
SELECT A.lAccountID 
      ,A.SomeData 
      ,(
        SELECT D.lAccountID
              ,D.sName
              ,D.sAge
        FROM @dummyAccountDetail AS D
        WHERE D.lAccountID=A.lAccountID
        FOR XML PATH('Values'),ROOT('Accounts'),TYPE
       )

FROM @dummyAccount AS A
```

You can easily create the table `#tmpAccount` just with

```
SELECT ...
INTO #tmpAccount
FROM ...
```

...or, if it exists already, just use

```
INSERT INTO #tmpAccount
SELECT ...
```

Comment: @SenjutiMahapatra I'm glad to read this! Just one hint: Since you've crossed the 15 rep point border you are asked to vote on contributions. Accepting and voting are two different steps. It would be very nice to vote Mr. Bhosale's answer up, as it was good enough for your acceptance before... If you want to, you might additionally vote my answer up to. The whole voting is up to you of course, but it's the fuel SO is running with...

Comment: Yes no problem. Voted up :)

Answer (score 1):

Check This.

```
         select distinct  
        (
          select 
          lAccountID,
          sName,
          sAge
         from 
          AccountDVDetails 
          where 
          laccountID = 10 
        for xml  raw ('Values'), ROOT ('Accounts'), ELEMENTS  
         )as XMLValue
         ,lAccountID into #tmpAccount  from  AccountDVDetails 
         where
         laccountID = 10 

         select * from #tmpAccount
```